# Report of sudo usage

Tags: linux, sudo

How do I get a report (either CSV or an Excel file) on who is using `sudo` on my machine, and which account they're switching to?

Comment: Please state your distribution. On Debian sudo logs are written to `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 3):

On UNIX-like systems, `sudo` is typically configured to log to a text file. For example, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux systems that is usually `/var/log/secure`, but it may be configured differently on your system. You should consult your system's man pages for information on how it is configured in your environment. Once you've confirmed your system's configuration, you should be able to easily find the information you are seeking via one of the text reading commands like `less` or `more`.